# Pandas delete first n rows until condition on columns is fulfilled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I am trying to delete some rows from my dataframe. In fact I want to delete the the first `n` rows, while `n` should be the row number of a certain condition. I want the dataframe to start with the row that contains the `x-y values` `xEnd,yEnd`. All earlier rows shall be dropped from the dataframe. Somehow I do not get the solution. That is what i have so far.

Example:

```
import pandas as  pd
xEnd=2
yEnd=3
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'y':[1,2,3,3,4,3], 'id':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})
n=df["id"].iloc[df["x"]==xEnd and df["y"]==yEnd]
df = df.iloc[n:]
```

I want my code to reduce the dataframe from

```
{'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'y':[1,2,3,3,4,3], 'id':[0,1,2,3,4,5]}
```

to

```
{'x':[2,2,2], 'y':[3,4,3], 'id':[3,4,5]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use `&` instead of `and`
- Use `loc` instead of `iloc`.  You can use `iloc` but it could break depending on the index
- Use `idxmax` to find the first positiopn

---

```
#             I used idxmax to find the index |
#                                             v
df.loc[((df['x'] == xEnd) & (df['y'] == yEnd)).idxmax():]
# ^
# | finding the index goes with using loc

   id  x  y
3   3  2  3
4   4  2  4
5   5  2  3
```

---

Here is an `iloc` variation

```
#    I used values.argmax to find the position |
#                                              v
df.iloc[((df['x'] == xEnd) & (df['y'] == yEnd)).values.argmax():]
# ^
# | finding the position goes with using iloc

   id  x  y
3   3  2  3
4   4  2  4
5   5  2  3
```

Comment: thanks a lot @piRSquared! Works perfectly fine! I am new to python and like pandas a lot but you have to get used to it

Comment: There is a learning curve just like everything else (-: have fun!

Comment: One more point: .`argmin()` or `idxmin()` would drop the oder 3 rows is that correct?

Comment: In this case, yes.  `argmin` will find that the first position in which the condition is `True` is in the third position.  We then slice `[3:]` which gets rid of rows `[0, 1, 2]`.  Because your index is already ordered `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` then `idxmax` with `loc` will work the same way.

Comment: Well I just tried it out, it does not work like that. How would I achieve the opposite? dropping the rows that come after my condition?

Answer (score 2):

Using `cummax`

```
df[((df['x'] == xEnd) & (df['y'] == yEnd)).cummax()]
Out[147]: 
   id  x  y
3   3  2  3
4   4  2  4
5   5  2  3
```